# For each sequence on $\mathbb{R}^n$ is true that I have $n$-sequences. And vice-versa, given $n-$sequences I get one sequence on $\mathbb{R}^n?$

Tags: sequences-and-series, analysis

For each sequence on $\mathbb{R}^n$ is true that I have $n$-sequences. And vice-versa, given $n-$sequences I get one sequence on $\mathbb{R}^n?$

The point of this question is: Can I see a sequence on $\mathbb{R}^n$ as $n-$sequences on $\mathbb{R}?$

Comment: Yes: this is perfectly valid.

Comment: @Crostul, that was what I thought. For each sequence on $\mathbb{R}$ I have the $n-$sequences of each component... This question emerged when I was trying to prove that arbitrary product of compacts is compact. For this, suppose that it is not. Then there is a net on the product such that none sub-net of such net converges.  Well, if it is true for any subnet, I can project my net on one of the sets of the product. Then for this net, by hypothesis, there is none subsequence that converges. What gives me a contradiction..

Comment: There is a problem. Your net may not have a convergent subnet in the product, but this does not imply that projecting the same holds. Actually you have no contradiction.

Comment: @Crostul, you are right. Take $(x_{\lambda})$ a universal net. For each $i$, where $\{X_i : i \in I\}$ are compact for every $i$, $\pi((x_{\lambda}))$ is a universal net, for each $i$. Once each $X_i$ is compact, then each $\pi((x_{\lambda}))$ has a sequence with a limit $x_i$. Take $x = (x_i)_{i\in I}.$